# Did I interpret/transcribe chord names correctly?

Tags: chord-theory

I'm learning chord names and the musical staff notation at the same time.  I thought it would be a good exercise to write down exactly what notes are being played when I see something like this written: "C E7 Am D7/F#".

For example, I found this musical score for Mary Had a Little Lamb:

[image]

Then I wrote it as this:

[image]

Did I transcribe the chord names correctly in the second image?

Comment: Looks good, the last chord can be a Dm9 if you include the melody note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All of your chords are named and spelled correctly.